# Equivalent of Hive's date_format function in Impala?

Tags: hive, hiveql, impala

Is there an equivalent of Hive's date_format function in Impala?
I need to change a date column to the first day of the month (e.g., '2020-09-29' to '2020-09-01'), so I had originally used: `date_format(LOG_DATE,'yyyy-MM-01') as FIRST_DAY_MONTH`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Impala : -

You can use `to_timestamp()`.
Pls use this `to_timestamp('20200901','yyyyMMdd')` to get a timestamp.
Generic command may be `to_timestamp(concat(substr(data_col,1,7),'-01'),'yyyy-MM-dd')`

Hive : -
You need to use to get a timestamp.
`from_unixtime( unix_timestamp('20200901','yyyyMMdd'))`

Comment: No matching function with signature: to_timestamp(TIMESTAMP, STRING).

Comment: This question was for Impala so i answered for Impala. I added hive solution too.